# UnboundLocalError at /Movies/ local variable 'pichuur' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views

ERROR MSG:

[image]

The web page throws another view when I am trying to create another view and see the contents I have saved in the DB.

In **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class pichuur(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '-' + self.language


    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Genre= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Year= models.CharField
    Category= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Cast= models.CharField(max_length=500)`

    from django.shortcuts import render
```

in `views.py`:

```
# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import pichuur

def index(request):

    Sab_movies = pichuur.objects.all()
    html=''
    for pichuur in Sab_movies:
      url= '/Movies/' + str(pichuur.id) + '/'
      html+= '<a href= "'+ url + '">' + '</a><br>'

    return HttpResponse("<h> Welcome to Movies </h>")

    def detail(request, pichuur_id):
        return HttpResponse("<h2> Details for Movie Id:" + str(pichuur_id) + "</h2>")
```

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot for errors. Django error pages have a 'text friendly' version, linked from the page. Please use that link to copy the text version, paste that error here. Then select all of that text just copied and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to then format that error information. Make sure to include the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `pichuur` as a *local* variable in the `for` loop:

```
for pichuur in Sab_movies:
```

This means Python expects to be able to assign to it, and before the `for` loop starts, the name is *unbound*, has no value assigned to it.

That that name is *also* the name of your model doesn't matter any more. So the statement `Sab_movies = pichuur.objects.all()` fails, because `pichuur` is not yet set by the `for` loop.

The solution is to use a *different names* for your model and the loop target variable. Don't reuse model names as local variable names. And in the Python style guide, classes (such as Django models) should use CamelCase names, precisely to avoid mistakes like these.

So here specifically, I'd rename the model to use an uppercase `P`:

```
class Pichuur(models.Model):
```

then in `views.py` use that new name:

```
from .models import Pichuur
```

and

```
Sab_movies = Pichuur.objects.all()
```